# Problema con servicio Web Api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hola tengo un problema con el servicio, lo tengo publicado en una carpeta en GoDaddy en un servidor de Windows, pero no es muy diciente el error, si me pudieran ayudar muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La descripción del error te indica que es lo que sucede: tu servicio quiere realizar una operación la cual requiere ciertos permisos para ejecutar.

En este punto, el conocimiento que tengas de las operaciones que realice el servicio, es lo que tendrás que configurar en el servidor, o cambiar el nivel de confianza de la aplicación desde el archivo de configuración del servicio.

Cambiar nivel de confianza desde archivo de configuración [Info en inglés]:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx